# Размытие. Эффект затухания при запуске приложения

Tags: java, android, blur

я бы хотел реализовать эффект затухания на основе Blur, или как это называется, при запуске приложения. То есть радиус размытия становиться нулевым за пару секунд.

[Видео](https://vk.com/im?sel=c61&z=video239185791_456239138%2F6ea68d568642a7f5aa)

При запуске приложения (Сразу же после показа splashscreen), создается слой Blur (библиотека RealtimeBlurView), создается поток который в цикле for уменьшает радиус размытия, с задержкой.

И выходит, что у меня на телефоне (Xiaomi Mi5) все работает замечательно, но на более слабых телефонах уже лагает. Лагает на Samsung Galaxy S4 (GT-I9515).

Как можно добиться того же эффекта, но чтобы работало везде, и без лагов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Блюр - очень тяжелый эффект. Размытие по Гауссу, имеет сложность r^2 для каждого пикселя. то есть общая сложность алгоритма O(width * height * r^2). Если вы ставите внушительный радиус то вполне можете не уложиться во время кадра, отсюда и тормоза. Пропишите зависимость максимального радиуса размытия от телефона. Еще можете попробовать вместо параллельного потока менять  радиус с помощью ValueAnimator

Ну и последний вариант: найти решение с использованием OpenGL или сделать такой самому. По беглому изучению библиотеки она не только графику не приплетает, но и не оптимизирует размытие. Хотя может не туда смотрел

Comment: Gl ES  и придется писать шейдер самому я полагаю.